# How to open/transfer .fla files from one computer to another?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have been working on a project in flash as a test for a potential employer.  They requested that I include my .fla in my reply, but after I sent the file, they have been unable to open it.

Do I need to send more files than just the .fla so that other computers can open it?  I'm wondering if I need to include my .psd, the actionscript, and so forth.  I'm also worried that my version of Flash (which is the newest one) might be incompatible if they are using an old one.  In short, I'm not sure if I'm packaging it wrong or if there's a compatibility issue, or what kind of questions I should be asking to try and fix it.

If anyone could offer some insight I'd appreciate it; I already have the work done and it would be sad if I couldn't send it!

Comment: First step is to ask them what version of the Flash IDE they have.

Comment: If they want the source code, then you have to send everything (fla, psd, actionscript class files, etc). If you just need to send the working example, you might be able to send just the .swf file that the project makes.

Comment: Thanks - I created a separate layer and used it for all my actionscript, rather than creating a separate .as file.  Do you know if I need to individually access that file then, and if so, where flash stores it?  I sent the .swf earlier with my previous .fla, but doesn't seem like they want it.

Comment: I think a conversation with your potential employer to solve this issue efficiently, is going to do alot more for your chances than any of this conversation. They asked for the .fla, so it's safe to assume thats what they want.  If you don't get on the same page with your potential employer, none of this is going to matter.

Comment: I've sent an email to them before posting here, but simply put, it's a competitive job and I'm worried they won't be bothered to deal with my problem.  I told them the version of Flash I'm using and that I was worried about compatibility problems.  The message they sent me was "We are not able to open some of your docs.  Please submit them in a zip file, not .fla or .swf" -which made no sense to me, as they originally requested the .fla, and the files I sent were all in a zip.  I asked about that too, currently awaiting a response.

Comment: I wouldn't waste anymore time with those tools if I where you. It sounds like you are not even getting past HR

Answer (score 0):

First step is to ask them what version of the Flash IDE they have. If they have an older version, such as cs3 or cs4, they won't be able to open your .fla

I have gone through this process before when I had cs5.5 of saving to cs4, then going to cs4 and saving to cs3. Not a really ideal solution, but it's what I had to do.

I had heard that Flash CC was supposed to support saving all the way back to CS3. But I just checked now, and it doesn't allow me to save as anything but current version and a .xfl

My understanding is that if you save your file as a .xfl, then someone with CS5.5 or CS6 can open your file, but I don't believe that CS4 or CS3 can.

However, I have not actually tried that as I don't currently have any older versions of flash installed at the moment.